# how to create html table results from JSON data

Tags: json, ajax, html-table

I have code that uses AJAX and JSON to output a chunk of SQL data when you do a search and I am trying to separate the data some and have it display into an HTML table. At first it was just the SQL data but I put some tags into the innerHTML line to at least visually separate it, however I would really like to be able to put each column into a separate table cell. Any ideas on how to do that would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>AJAX Search Example</title>
    <script>
    function fetch() {
      // (A) GET SEARCH TERM
 
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('search', document.getElementById("search").value);
      data.append('ajax', 1);

      // (B) AJAX SEARCH REQUEST
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
      // (CHANGE1) USING ONREADYSTATECHNAGE INSTEAD OF ONLOAD
      
    xhr.onreadystatechange =  function (event) {
        // (CHANGE2) we will check if ajax process has completed or not it goes from 1,2,3,4 means end. 

if(this.readyState == 4){

// (CHANGE2) when ready state comes to 4 we then check what response status was it if it is 200 good else error. 

if(this.status == 200){
    // (CHANGE3) MOVED ALL YOUR CODE HERE 

// (CHANGE4) we need to use responseText instead of response because JSON comes as string that is why we are parsing it to be converted into array

var results = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    //I have added just a measure to check what the out put is you can remove it latter. open dev console to get the result.
    console.log(results);

wrapper = document.getElementById("results");
    if (results.length > 0) {
          wrapper.innerHTML = "";

// (CHANGE5) UPDATED data ref with results 

for (i = 0; i <  results.length; i++) {
            let line = document.createElement("div");
              //it is just as simple to create id only it must start with alphabet not number 

line.id=`res${[i]}`;

//we created span tag to display price and this is what we will change. on that span we will create a data-price attribute which will hold original price and we will run calculations using that number 

//BIG CHANGE
//BIG CHANGE

//since after parsing individual record will be in Js object so we dont need to access them like array  results[i]['item']

//we access them with dot notation results[i].item

line.innerHTML = `Category:${results[i].category} - OEM #:${results[i].oemnumber} - Price:$<span data-price='${results[i].price}'>${results[i].price}</span>
            select discount >>   
            <a href="#70">%70</a>
    <a href="#60">%60</a>
    <a href="#50">%50</a> <a href="#50">100%</a>`; 
            wrapper.appendChild(line);
          }

 // (CHANGE6) We moved event listeners here so any newly added elements will be updated. 

 //get all the links and apply event listener through loop   
 
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
      

      for ( ii = 0; ii <  links.length; ii++) {
         links[ii].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
         
       //capture link value and get number to be converted to percentage  
       
       var percentage = event.target.innerText.match(/\d+/)[0]/100;
 
 //capture the data-price which is within same div as anchor link
 
 var pricetarget = event.target.parentElement.querySelector('[data-price]');
 
 //get value of data-price
 
 var actualprice=  pricetarget.dataset.price;
 
 //run math and chnage the value on display
 
 pricetarget.innerHTML=(actualprice*percentage).toFixed(2);
      
      
      });
      }

        } else { wrapper.innerHTML = "No results found"; }

 } else {
 
 //if reponse code is other ethan 200 

alert('INTERNET  DEAD OR AJAX FAILED ');

 }

 }
       

            

      };

// (CHANGE7) We moved open event to end so everything is ready before it fires.

xhr.open('POST', "2-search.php");
      xhr.send(data);
      return false;

 
    };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- (A) SEARCH FORM -->
    <form ID='myForm' onsubmit="return fetch();">
      <h1>SEARCH FOR CATALYTIC CONVERTER</h1>
      <input type="text" id="search" required/>
      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>

    <!-- (B) SEARCH RESULTS -->
    <div id="results"></div>


  </body>
  </html>
```

Here is where I added the tags to at least visually separate it: "line.innerHTML = `Category:${results[i].category} - OEM #:${results[i].oemnumber} - Price:$${results[i].price}"

What I want to do is have Category, OEM #, and price each in a separate table cell. Thank you for any help offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply generate `trs` inside your  `for (i = 0; i < results.len..` like you are already doing for divs . So , just use `+=` to append every new `tr` inside `tbody` and then append this to your table

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//suppose json look like below :)
var results = [{
  "category": "A",
  "price": 13,
  "oemnumber": "d1A"
}, {
  "category": "B",
  "price": 15,
  "oemnumber": "d1B"
}, {
  "category": "C",
  "price": 12,
  "oemnumber": "d1C"
}]
fetch();

function fetch() {
  /*  var data = new FormData();
   data.append('search', document.getElementById("search").value);
   data.append('ajax', 1);
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

   // (CHANGE1) USING ONREADYSTATECHNAGE INSTEAD OF ONLOAD

     //some codes/..    
    console.log(results);*/

  wrapper = document.getElementById("results");
  wrapper.innerHTML = "";
  var rows = "";
  if (results.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      //generate trs
      rows += `<tr id=res${[i]}><td>${results[i].category}</td><td>${results[i].oemnumber}</td><td>$<span data-price='${results[i].price}'>${results[i].price}</span>
            select discount >>   
            <a href="#70">%70</a>
    <a href="#60">%60</a>
    <a href="#50">%50</a> <a href="#50">100%</a></td></tr>`;
    }
    wrapper.innerHTML = `<table class="table">
    <thead><th>Category</th><th>OEM</th><th>Price</th></thead><tbody>${rows}</tbody></table>`;

    //sme other codes,,

  }
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="results">
</div>
```

Comment: I did the innerhtml part before but without the div part, maybe that is why it didn't work. I do not need the "+=" between each data result though?Like "wrapper.innerHTML += `<tr id=res${[i]}> += <td>${results[i].category}</td> += <td>${results[i].oemnumber}</td> += <td>$<span data-price='${results[i].price}'>${results[i].price}</span>"

Comment: One question,you have " wrapper = document.getElementById("somethings");" I have results there instead of somethings to go with the <div id="results">, now in your html you have <div id="results"> and <tbody id="somethings">. If I change the tag from results to somethings then results will be missing for the div tag. So how do I get the tag for the div and the tag for the table?

Comment: No , `somethings` is inside `results` div you can keep result div hidden at first after datas are loaded from ajax you can show result div and then append json inside your `tbody` .

Comment: OK, what I was asking was in your demo code you changed my "wrapper = document.getElementById("results");" to "wrapper = document.getElementById("somethings");". How would I go about having both the results and somethings tab in the code?

Comment: So you need to add table generated inside `results` div ? If yes you can simply generate whole table in your js code.. and then append that to your result div .

Comment: Yes, I need the results diplayed in a table inside the results Div. Would I basically use this to create the table "var table = document.createElement("TABLE");", if so I will work on that and figure out how to get it to dynamically assign the number of rows based on number of results. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my answer please have a look.

Comment: So I replace "line.innerHTML" with the "rows +=" and the "wrapper.appendChild(line)" with the "wrapper.innerHTML"? I know that's not all I need to change, but am I replacing those things with your code?

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing at your end and above answer is just for demo .You need to adapt it in your code according to your requirement.